# java - ResultSet displaying as String

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

I am using the ucanaccess tool to interact with my access database, but I do not know how to display or store the resulting ResultSets as Strings.

Edit: I have tried =`System.out.println(resultSetId.getString(1));` but that only returns errors.
    `ResultSet resultSetId;
    String msAccDB = "D://Computer Science//passManager//src//Manager.accdb";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + msAccDB;
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSetId = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM Passwords WHERE ID = 
    \""+identifier+"\";");
    System.out.println(resultSetId.getString(1));`

Gives the error `Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Ucanaccess`enter code here`SQLException: invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is positioned before first row`

Edit: Adding the .next() fixed it, thanks!

Comment: what have you tried? what went wrong? what's in the resultset?

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Comment: post your code with error you got in stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ResultSet is positioned before first row

When `executeQuery` returns the `ResultSet` it is not pointing at a row of data. You need to call `resultSetId.next()` in order to retrieve each row. That is often done in the context of a `while` loop when the `ResultSet` is expected to return more than one row, e.g.,

```java
while (resultSetId.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSetId.getString(1));  // print value from each row
}
```

but you can simply call it once if you only expect a single row, e.g.,

```java
if (resultSetId.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSetId.getString(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("The ResultSet contained no rows.");
}
```